# Trying to delete message that notifies a role being added a few seconds after the message is sent in a specific role channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Part of my discord bot has a reaction role event. I got the reaction role part to work but I want it to add a message to the react role channel. I got that part to work as well. However, I cannot get the bot to delete the message that it sent the channel a few seconds later. I tried the `await delete()` function but it is not working. 
Here is the code:

```
if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('>>>Role Added.')
                channel = client.get_channel(692231831885709322)
                m = await channel.send('Regional Role was added')
                await # delete message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [delete coroutine](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) has a delay parameter. You can use that to set a delay before deleting in seconds.

```
if member is not None:
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print('>>>Role Added.')
    channel = client.get_channel(692231831885709322)
    m = await channel.send('Regional Role was added')
    await m.delete(delay = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks you! This works just how I wanted it too. I tried something like this before but I was getting an error saying 2 arguments were given but one is expected but this works now.